# Can the MediaElement.js be used to play audio for IE6-8,Firefox and Opera?

Tags: javascript, audio, browser, html5-audio, mediaelement.js

Can the MediaElement.js be used to play audio for IE6-8,Firefox and Opera? If yes, how do we provide the fallback for getting the audio playing for the above?

The code I am using is

```
<div class="audio-player">
    <audio id="audio-player" src="sample.mp3" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls"></audio>
</div>
```

It works fine in the latest versions, but I would like to test for the lower versions mentioned above and can you also let me know which browsers are being supported and what code should i add for the audio to be working on the lower versions.

Thanks and appreciate your response at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just playing mp3 audio as in your example, then you don't need to set a fallback to play in different browsers. These 3 options will work with your current html element in Firefox, Opera, IE6+, Chrome (and most modern browsers)

1). Initialize all `audio` elements with MEJS

```
$("audio").mediaelementplayer({
    // API options
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gUYs2/)**

2). Initialize your own selector

```
$("#audio-player").mediaelementplayer({
    // API options
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gUYs2/1/)**

3). Explicitly create a MediaElementPlayer object for your own use

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#audio-player', {
    // API options
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gUYs2/2/)**

---

Additionally, you could set different API options and/or add *event* listeners within the `success` setting like :

```
var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#audio-player', {
    // API options
    success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
        // optionally call the play method
        mediaElement.play();
        // or set MEJS events
        // note : canplay event won't work if preload="none"
        mediaElement.addEventListener('playing', function () {
            // audio is playing, do something here
        }, false);
        mediaElement.addEventListener('pause', function () {
            // audio was paused, do something here
        }, false);
    }
});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gUYs2/3/)**